# Text to Mtext within Area - autocad

Tags: autocad, autocad-plugin, autolisp

I have the following code.  It creates text to mtext without moving the text blocks in autocad.  I want to have this script but combine the text lines into one block within a certain area.  As in create a block of mtext within 5 units north and south of a certain layer's text blocks.

```
(defun C:T1MJ ; = Text or Attribute Definition to 1-line Mtext, retaining Justification
  (/ *error* cmde doc tss inc tent tobj tins tjust)

  (defun *error* (errmsg)
    (if (not (wcmatch errmsg "Function cancelled,quit / exit abort,console break"))
      (princ (strcat "\nError: " errmsg))
    ); if
    (vla-endundomark doc)
    (setvar 'cmdecho cmde)
    (princ)
  ); defun - *error*

  (setq
    cmde (getvar 'cmdecho)
    doc (vla-get-activedocument (vlax-get-acad-object))
  ); setq
  (vla-startundomark doc)
  (setvar 'cmdecho 0)
  (prompt "\nTo change Text/Attribute to 1-line Mtext, preserving Justification,")
  (if (setq tss (ssget "_:L" '((0 . "TEXT,ATTDEF"))))
    (repeat (setq inc (sslength tss))
      (setq
        tent (ssname tss (setq inc (1- inc)))
        tobj (vlax-ename->vla-object tent)
        tins (vlax-get tobj 'TextAlignmentPoint)
        tjust (vla-get-Alignment tobj)
      ); setq
      (cond
        ((= tjust 0) (setq tjust 7 tins (vlax-get tobj 'InsertionPoint))); Left
        ((< tjust 3) (setq tjust (+ tjust 7))); 1/2 [Center/Right] to 8/9
        ((= tjust 4) (setq tjust 5)); Middle to Middle-Center
        ((member tjust '(3 5)); Aligned/Fit
          (setq
            tjust 8 ; to Bottom-Center
            tins (mapcar '/ (mapcar '+ (vlax-get tobj 'InsertionPoint) tins) '(2 2 2))
              ; with new insertion point
          ); setq
        ); Aligned/Fit
        ((setq tjust (- tjust 5))); all vertical-horizontal pair justifications
      ); cond
      (if (= (vla-get-TextString tobj) "") (vla-put-TextString tobj (vla-get-TagString tobj)))
        ;; if no default content, disappears after TXT2MTXT: impose Tag value for it
        ;; [to use Prompt value instead, change end to (vla-get-PromptString tobj).]
      (command "_.txt2mtxt" tent ""); convert, then
      (setq tobj (vlax-ename->vla-object (entlast))); replace Text as object with new Mtext
      (vla-put-AttachmentPoint tobj tjust); original Text's justification [or equiv.]
      (vlax-put tobj 'InsertionPoint tins); original Text's insertion
    ); repeat
  ); if
  (setvar 'cmdecho cmde)
  (vla-endundomark doc)
  (princ)
); defun -- T1MJ
(vl-load-com)
(prompt "\nType T1MJ to change Text/Attribute-Definitions to 1-line Mtext, preserving Justification.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a lisp programmer so I can't give you a direct answer but I am about to describe a concept to you that you should be able to replicate.

If you look here at this web resource it discusses one of the **Express Tools**: [TXT2MTXT](http://www.ellenfinkelstein.com/acadblog/tutorial-convert-text-to-mtext-and-vice-versa/)

[image: TXT2MTXT]

Now, this is a command line routine and it takes a selection set and converts the **TEXT** into a **MTEXT** object:

[image: MTEXT]

So, I can't see why you can't use lisp to make a localized selection set of your text objects and then pass this selection set to the **TXT2MTXT** command. I know it is possible to do this kind of thing with lisp. I just don't know the mechanics. I know VBA.

I hope this is of assistance to you in resolve your issue. It doesn't show the code but it describes the concept of how to do what you want.